# Python script to scrape tables from 24 pages with a blank header and output a csv

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, header

The company i work for is migrating from one service to another. We need to migrate the member profiles from the old site to the new. The new site supports import via csv. I am admittedly not a programmer and relying heavily on ChatGPT. I am familiar with coding as i used to make websites and have tried learning java, so i am comfortable working with code. We are a small 501c3 and i am just trying to save us some money. I cannot post any data as it is HIPAA protected Personally Identifying Information.

The issue i am running into is that the source data first column header is empty and under that header is the picture data. When making the scraper i cannot get it to scrape the blank header which causes a data shift.

The end goal is to scrape everything from 24 pages so it is formatted correctly, then completely delete column A and shift everything left 1 cell including headers.

The tables are made in this manner:

```
<div class="facetwp-selections"></div><div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="facetwp-template">
        <div class="panel panel-flat">
            <div class="table-responsive obh-scrollable obh-attendance" id='obh-all-members-table'>
                <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr role="row">
         <!--This is the empty header that needs to be scraped as well --><th></th>
                                <th><h3 class="no-margin">Name</h3></th>
                                <th><h3 class="no-margin">Phone</h3></th>
                                <th><h3 class="no-margin">Email</h3></th>
                                <th><h3 class="no-margin">Status</h3></th>
                                <th><h3 class="no-margin">Tags</h3></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                    <!--fwp-loop-->
    
                            <tr role="row">
                                <td style="padding-right:0px">
                                    <a href="[member profile]"><img class="obh_m_avatar" src="[img].jpg" width="40" style="border-radius:50%;"></a>                             </td>
                                <td class="obh-export" style="padding-left:10px;min-width:175px;">
                                        <a href="[member profile]">John Smith</a>                               </td>
                                <td class="obh-export" style="min-width:185px;">
                                                                    </td>
                                <td class="obh-export">
                                    <a target="_blank" href="mailto: email">email@example.com</a>                               </td>
                                <td class="obh-export">
                                                                    </td>
                                <td class="obh-export">
                                                                    </td>
                            </tr>
```

I have tried multiple methods, this was the most successful in an earlier (unsaved of course) version, however now nothing is being output, not even an error. Previously it was giving an error that the headers were not identified because it was not looking for a  method. This is just trying to get the data, i have not added the code to remove column A yet.

```
import os
import csv
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Specify the full path to the error report log file
error_log_path = r"C:\[path]\error_log.txt"

# URL of the login page
login_url = "https://[url].com/sign-in/"

# Base URL of the webpage to be scraped after login
base_scrape_url = "https://[url].com/members/?_paged={}&_per_page=100"

# Login credentials using setx in cmd
username = os.environ.get('USERNAME')
password = os.environ.get('PASSWORD')

# Initialize a session object
session = requests.Session()

# Submit a POST request to the login page with the login credentials
login_data = {"username": username, "password": password}
response = session.post(login_url, data=login_data)

try:
    # Check if the login was successful
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print("Login failed. Status code:", response.status_code)
        exit()

    # Create a list to store the table data from all pages
    all_rows = []

    # Extract the headers from the first page
    # Send a GET request to the first page
    response = session.get(base_scrape_url.format(1))
    # Parse the HTML content of the response using BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    # Extract the column headers from the header row
    thead = soup.find("thead")
    header_row = thead.find("tr")
    headers = [''] + [th.find("h3").text.strip() for th in header_row.find_all("th")]

    # Loop through all pages
    for page_num in range(1, 25):
        # Construct the URL for the current page
        scrape_url = base_scrape_url.format(page_num)
        
        # Wait for 1 second before proceeding to the next page
        time.sleep(1)

        # Send a GET request to the current page
        response = session.get(scrape_url)

        # Parse the HTML content of the response using BeautifulSoup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        # Extract the table data from the body rows
        tbody = soup.find("tbody")
        for tr in tbody.find_all("tr"):
            # Extract the data from each cell in the row
            row_data = [''] + [td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all("td")]
            # Combine the header and data into a dictionary
            row_dict = dict(zip(headers, row_data))
            # Add the row to the list of all rows
            all_rows.append(row_dict)

    # Write the table data to a CSV file
    with open(r"C:\[path]\Master.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(all_rows)

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"Error fetching {url}: {e}")
    with open(error_log_path, "a") as f:
        f.write(f"Error fetching {url}: {e}")
        f.write("\n")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error parsing {url}: {e}")
    with open(error_log_path, "a") as f:
        f.write(f"Error parsing {url}: {e}")
        f.write("\n")
```

The following code is outputting a master csv but it is empty and there is an error log which says:

```
Error: name 'headers' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:path\scraper.py", line 95, in <module>
    writer.writerow(headers)
                    ^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'headers' is not defined
```

This data also has a cell with some unneeded information which ends up in like F35 so added handling to remove the unneeded data. That is not imperative right now, just explaining why the sudden addition.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import openpyxl
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
import traceback
import os
import time

# Specify the full path to the error report log file
error_log_path = r"C:\[path]\error_log.txt"

# URL of the login page
login_url = "https://[url]/sign-in/"

# Base URL of the webpage to be scraped after login
base_scrape_url = "https://[url].com/members/?_paged={}&_per_page=100"

# Login credentials using setx in cmd
username = os.environ.get('USERNAME')
password = os.environ.get('PASSWORD')

# Initialize a session object
session = requests.Session()

# Submit a POST request to the login page with the login credentials
login_data = {"username": username, "password": password}
response = session.post(login_url, data=login_data)

try:
    # Check if the login was successful
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print("Login failed. Status code:", response.status_code)
        exit()

    # Create a list to store the table data from all pages
    all_rows = []

    # Loop through all pages
    for page_num in range(1, 25):
        # Construct the URL for the current page
        scrape_url = base_scrape_url.format(page_num)
        
        # Wait for 1 second before proceeding to the next page
        time.sleep(1)

        # Send a GET request to the current page
        response = session.get(scrape_url)

        # Parse the HTML content of the response using BeautifulSoup
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        # Find the first table on the webpage
        table = soup.find("table")

        # Extract the table headers
        if table:
            headers = []
            for th in table.find_all("th"):
                headers.append(th.text)

            # Extract the table rows and data
            rows = []
            for tr in tqdm(table.find_all("tr")[1:]):
                # Skip the first column (picture) and extract the rest of the row data
                data = [td.text for td in tr.find_all("td")[1:]]
                # Check if the row contains "CLOTHING ASSISTANCE" and "TRANSPORTATION"
                if "CLOTHING ASSISTANCE" in data and "TRANSPORTATION" in data:
                    # Set the values of these cells to None
                    data[data.index("CLOTHING ASSISTANCE")] = None
                    data[data.index("TRANSPORTATION")] = None
                else:
                    # Shift the remaining cells left by one column
                    for i in range(len(data)):
                        if i == 0:
                            continue
                        elif "CLOTHING ASSISTANCE" in data[i] and "TRANSPORTATION" in data[i]:
                            data[i] = None
                        else:
                            data[i-1] = data[i]
                            data[i] = None
                rows.append(data)


            # Add the table data from the current page to the list of all rows
            all_rows.extend(rows)

    # Write the table data to a .csv file
    output_folder = r"C:\[path]"
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)
    output_path = os.path.join(output_folder, "Master.csv")
    with open(output_path, "w", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        # Write the headers as the first row
        writer.writerow(headers)
        # Write the remaining rows of data
        writer.writerows(all_rows)


except Exception as e:
    # Log any errors that occur to the error report log file
    with open(error_log_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(f"Error: {e}\n")
        f.write(traceback.format_exc())
```